# Google Sheets apps script works for me but not other users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a custom user form loadForm() which basically serves up html in a dialog. This gets called by onOpenInstalledTrigger() whenever user opens the spreadsheet. User enters information which is captured as values for my spreadsheet via an appendData() function called by a submit button on the html form in the dialog.

It works perfectly fine for me, but not for my colleagues. They have edit permissions for the Google Sheet. For them, it seems like onOpenInstalledTrigger() works, which calls loadForm(), which works. The custom form appears. However, when they click submit which calls my appendData() function, it fails.

```
function appendData(data){
  var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("feed");
  ws.appendRow([data.title,data.url,data.topics,data.questions,data.date,data.tags]);
 
  var cell = ws.getRange(ws.getLastRow(),6);
  ws.setCurrentCell(cell);
  cell.splitTextToColumns();
  Logger.log(data);
  return true;
}
```

Any idea what I might be missing? Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a public copy of all files (can be dummy data) and how are they shared to the other users?

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure what files to share. My project is a simple spreadsheet as a database for my team to curate news articles that are relevant to the course we are teaching (I'm a school teacher.) I have a separate web app that serves data from this sheet to a "latest news feed" (html is programmatically generated) of relevant articles to our students, with a simplistic filter-by-topic function.

Anyway, [here's a copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dV7SBO5xnIMOBv7vQ1Zb8FE7pu-5YllZhZ1tfzUQs_8/edit?usp=sharing) of what the sheet looks like with half-real-half-dummy data.

Comment: My colleagues are added as collaborators using the Google Sheets "share" function, through which I've given editing access to them.

Comment: Please provide a copy of the form and any javascript associated with it.

Comment: Hi there, I am not sure how to share a copy of the form other than by the html code, and if there's a convention for sharing longer pieces of code here, but here is the html file for my form with the script at the bottom.
https://carbon.now.sh/0TpIqOfEJCMWbhbxEY3b

Thank you for taking an interest in my issue.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your workflow, the sheet you shared does not have any code. Also, on the code you shared there is no loadForm() function. Can you update on it?

Comment: So this is the [apps script code](https://carbon.now.sh/ubp5a40hlNkmTbDoc4lF) that is bound to the sheet, and this is the [userform html that gets passed into the HtmlService function](https://carbon.now.sh/0TpIqOfEJCMWbhbxEY3b) (This is the same link as in the earlier comment.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I have shared the sheet with the script working to another account with edit permissions, and has been able to create a new register.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I do. Thanks for testing the script. At least i can confirm the script works. Perhaps I will need to contact my Workspace administrator to investigate the permissions settings or something.

Comment: Have you checked if creating a new file with the same script and test sheet does also give you this issue? Or maybe creating it from a personal gmail account and testing from that?